# Clean Install of Ubuntu 14.04 Lts on Windows 10 Laptop. BIOS Settings?

Tags: boot, uefi

I would like to do a clean installation of Ubuntu 14.04 LTS on an HP Pavilion G6 - 2399sa laptop. The laptop has Windows 10 installed. I want to format the HDD after running a live Ubuntu DVD and completely replace Windows 10 with Ubuntu. Should I change the BIOS settings from secure boot to legacy? I understand the boot order also needs to be changed to boot from the DVD first. When should these changes to the BIOS settings be made? I am very new to Linux and I don't have any technical experience. I did manage to install Linux Mint on another similar laptop that had Windows wiped, so there was no OS at all. The difference here is that Windows 10 is still installed on this laptop. If I allow the Ubuntu installation disk to format the HDD, would I have trouble booting up Ubuntu if I don't change the BIOS settings in advance?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First you're conflating two things:

- **Boot mode (BIOS/CSM/legacy vs. EFI/UEFI)** -- The vast majority of modern computers ship with EFI firmware, which boots natively in EFI mode. That firmware usually (but not always) provides a Compatibility Support Module (CSM), which enables the computer to boot BIOS-mode boot loaders. Using CSM is sometimes referred to as "legacy mode." (I assume that's what you meant by "legend.")
- **Secure Boot** -- This feature is one *optional* part of UEFI. Thus, it cannot be used with a BIOS-mode boot; but as it's optional, it does not need to be used in an EFI-mode boot, either. At least, not always -- a manufacturer could theoretically link the two so that EFI-mode booting requires use of Secure Boot. I've seen reports of machines that do this, but I'm skeptical -- firmware user interfaces are so complex, and often so poorly designed, that it's easy to get confused and misunderstand what feature are and are not linked together. In any event, even if some machines link them, most don't -- you can boot in EFI mode with or without Secure Boot enabled.

For a single-OS installation, it doesn't make much difference whether you boot in BIOS mode or in EFI mode. BIOS mode is likely to be more familiar to you if you've installed OSes in the past; but because the CSM is an add-on to modern firmware, performing a BIOS-mode installation actually complicates the boot path. An EFI-mode installation is likely to boot slightly more quickly than a BIOS-mode installation, but this difference will not be huge. There are more boot loader options for EFI-mode than for BIOS-mode, but Ubuntu uses GRUB by default for both boot modes.

If you go with an EFI-mode installation, you have the choice of using Secure Boot vs. not using it. In theory, there are advantages to Secure Boot, since it can block pre-boot malware from getting a grip on your computer. In practice, I have yet to hear of any widespread attacks that might be stopped by Secure Boot -- but such an attack might become common tomorrow. OTOH, Ubuntu's Secure Boot support adds complexity to the boot process and doesn't work on all computers -- a few just don't work with Ubuntu's tool (called "Shim"). Overall, if you go with an EFI-mode boot, I recommend you leave Secure Boot disabled unless you can't get your boot process to begin, in which case you might disable this feature. Note that if you get as far as an Ubuntu logo, you've passed the Secure Boot hurdle.

If you were to dual-boot, the first rule is to ensure that both OSes boot in the same mode. Since almost all computers that ship with Windows 8 and later boot Windows in EFI mode, that normally means installing Ubuntu in EFI mode. If you think you might re-install Windows in the future, you might be constrained to an EFI-mode boot, depending on how you install Windows. (Media provided by your computer's manufacturer might support only EFI-mode installations, but Microsoft's standard media support both boot modes.)

Comment: Great explanation of booting, especially as I'm so new to this - thanks. I apologise for my typo, I did mean legacy. I've only ever installed 2 OS. The first was Ubuntu 15.04 on my oldest laptop, no problem. I erased Windows Vista, installation and booting were fine. I then decided to 'rescue' another fairly new Windows 8 laptop which kept freezing, CPU   1.7 ghz. I tried to install Ubuntu LTS  but during installation I was told some files were corrupt, so left with no OS on laptop - shock horror! I changed BIOS settings and installed Mint instead. That's why I needed advice for the next time.

Answer (score 1):

During the Linux installation options, there is quite a bit of flexibility/control over how the disk is prepared.

Certainly one of the easiest is to overwrite the entire disk which would obliterate HP's recovery information as well as any existing installed operating systems.

Other options are to install Linux into a separate partition which automatically activates boot loader (GRUB I think for Ubuntu) options to selectively boot an operating system.  However, the partition holding Windows probably occupies basically the whole disk.  There are disk tools (like from Paragon) which resize a Windows partition and doing the right thing inside the NTFS volume to make it work right—if there is free space inside the volume.

Answer (score 0):

Additionally when you want to boot back into Windows, if you keep that OS, you have to re-enable secure boot in BIOS to get back to that OS

Comment: That is not correct

Comment: Oh ok,sorry. On my Toshiba Satellite I have to disable secure boot in order to boot into another OSand then re-enable to get back into Windows 10.

Comment: You shouldn't need to turn secure boot back on but I suppose it comes down to quirks of the firmware.

Comment: I'm having a bit of trouble myself with an installation, maybe you can be of assistance?

Comment: Go ahead and ask a question on the site. That's the best way to do it. But search for answers that help first. :)

Comment: Windows 8 and later is fine with Secure Boot either on or off. It could be that you're actually changing something else, or you've misidentified the nature of your boot problems.